# как запустить локальный wp-cli на удаленном PC

Tags: linux, wordpress, bash, ssh, консоль

у меня на локальном  *PC* установлен **wp-cli** 
я использую эту команду для работы с удаленным *PC*

```
wp --ssh=${connect} --path=${PATH} plugin list --allow-root
```

такой скрипт работает если на удаленном *PC* тоже установлен **wp-cli**

но если нет то терминал выдает ошибку

```
bash: wp: command not found
```

возможно ли заставить работать или как то передать локальный
**wp-cli** 
на удаленку без установки там **wp-cli**  ?

Comment: Никак. wp-cli не умеет сам себя куда-то копировать.

Comment: У вас не установлен wp-cli. Но установка вашу проблему не решит)